# Write files directly from flask app at Heroku to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working on a flask project in which I'm creating a JSON file from python dictionary. I want to push my JSON files directly to a s3 bucket.
How can I achieve that?

Sample data:

```
    data = {
    'uid': userId,
    'descriptions': description,
    'inputs': inputs,
    'outputs': outputs,
    'ex_inputs': example_input,
    'ex_outputs': example_output,
    'miscs': misc,
    'constraints': constraints
}

json_data = json.dumps(data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`boto3`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to talk to S3 from your python app.

This link might be a good start for you - http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3-examples.html

```
import json
import boto3

data = {}
data['name'] = "foo"
data['description'] = "bar"
json_data = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_object(Bucket='my-bucket', Key='key-name', Body=json_data)
```

put_object() - https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object

Comment: How can I create this file directly at S3? docs talk about file upload but I need to create the file directly at s3 bucket with a specific name.

Comment: updated the answer to include an example of s3.Object.put()

Comment: Where I can mention the file name? is it key-name?

Comment: yes. more info on S3 object keys - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys

Comment: Before you can put objects in S3 using boto3, you need create API keys from your AWS console and make them available to boto3 somehow. You should read this to figure out how to do that - http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

Comment: it says `AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'Object'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165316/discussion-between-prasadk-and-abdul-rehman).

Answer (score 0):

It's working with S3 put_object method.
My updated code is as:

```
key = 'description_' + str(fid) + '.json'
response = s3.put_object(Bucket='d2c-api2-bucket',
                         Body=json_data,
                         Key=key
                         )
```